Exporting from Grease pencil to SVG with Holes does not work properly?
I am trying to export a shape that I made in blender to an SVG. I've converted the curve to SVG, but all the holes get filled in the process. The work around to that was to assign the inner curves to a material that has hold out checked. This allows for the holes to become transparent when being rendered, but it is just black when being exported to an SVG. Is there no way to have holes in a shape and export it to an SVG?


Is it possible to export shapes like this as SVGs using blender?
I want them to be filled as well. So exporting with fill is necessary.
